# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) in xcode playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am trying to create a collection view class for my playground. I have this code. It is a class when I create a UICollectionView in Xcode playground to after it will use in my principal file.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

public class MenuCollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {
    public init(frame: CGRect) {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 38, alpha:1.0)

        self.register(MenuCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MenuCell")
    }

    required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }

    public func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MenuCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuCollectionViewCell

        cell.PlanetName.text = Constants.names[indexPath.row]
        cell.PlanetImage.image = UIImage(named: Constants.imagesNames[indexPath.row])?.cropToSquare().cropToCircle()

        return cell
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (self.frame.size.width/2)-10, height: (((self.frame.size.width/2)-10)*1.4)+25)
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MenuCollectionViewCell

        self.tag = indexPath.row

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: 0.3,
            delay: 0.0,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 1.1,
            initialSpringVelocity: 1.5,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
            animations: ({

                cell.PlanetImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)

            }), completion: {finished in
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MenuItemSelected"), object: nil)

                UIView.animate(
                    withDuration: 0.3,
                    delay: 0.0,
                    usingSpringWithDamping: 1.1,
                    initialSpringVelocity: 1.5,
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                    animations: ({

                        cell.PlanetImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)

                    }), completion: nil)
        })


    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5
    }
}
```

That error appears when I use the next line of code:

```
let menuView1 = MenuCollectionView(frame: CGRect.init(x: -(viewWidth/2.2), y: 0.0, width: viewWidth/2.2, height: viewHeight))
```

The error that appears when I run the project is:

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
>   The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

My version of Xcode is 9.2 and I use Swift 4. If you have any questions, please post a comment and I will give more information about the error.
[image: IMAGE TO DEBUGGER DATA]

Comment: Can you post what you see in the debug area?

Comment: @Xcoder I posted in my publication a capture of my debugger data